# Python - xmljson - save Cyrillic symbols

Tags: python, encoding

I have an xml, and I want to convert it to json using [xmljson](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/xmljson) lib. The xml is following

```
<description>Описание товара</description>
```

in console I do the following

```
>>> from xmljson import badgerfish as bf
>>> from xml.etree.ElementTree import fromstring
>>> from json import dumps
>>> dumps(bf.data(fromstring('<description>Описание товара</description>')))
```

and then I get

```
>>> '{"description": {"$": "\\u041e\\u043f\\u0438\\u0441\\u0430\\u043d\\u0438\\u0435 \\u0442\\u043e\\u0432\\u0430\\u0440\\u0430"}}'
```

What can I do in order to get `Описание товара` instead of `\\u041e\\u043f\\u0438\\u0441\\u0430\\u043d\\u0438\\u0435 \\u0442\\u043e\\u0432\\u0430\\u0440\\u0430`

Comment: Does your console display Cyrillic symbols correctly? This could be a console issue, not Python.

Comment: No, its not console issue. I tryed to run the same code inside Django and I got the same problem with symbols

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `ensure_ascii=False` in the `json.dumps`:

```
import xmltodict
import json
s = '<description>Описание товара</description>'
d = xmltodict.parse(s)
json.dumps(d, ensure_ascii=False)
# '{"description": "Описание товара"}'
```

Note: you can decode string manually:

```
st = "\\u041e\\u043f\\u0438\\u0441\\u0430\\u043d\\u0438\\u0435 \\u0442\\u043e\\u0432\\u0430\\u0440\\u0430"
st.encode('ascii').decode('unicode-escape')
# 'Описание товара'
```

Comment: It works fine in my case.  ensure_ascii=False and don't forget to use json_str = json_str.encode('utf-8') if you're going to print output to a file for example.